# how can I show the text from uitextfield to a label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uialertview

I am trying to show some text gained from a `textfield` of `uialertview`, than I want to show the text into a `UILabel` .

I am finding it difficult , could anybody pls help me ??

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender {

//http://useyourloaf.com/blog/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8/

UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Hello Crazy" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)
 {
     textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Pet Name", @"Name");
 }];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

   // self.labelText1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert.textFields.firstObject"];
   //  self.labelText1.text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"alert.textFields.firstObject"];
   self.labelText1.text = @" \?alert.textFields.firstObject\? ";

}];
[alert addAction:ok];


UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}];
[alert addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

here you can see I am trying to show the text in `self.labelText1.text` , here this labeltext1 accept a string , but I want to show the text gained from the `placeholder` of the `uialertview`. please give me some suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the textfield(s) using using `alert.textFields`, it's an array of `UITextField`. In your case the first object of that array contains the textfield that you want to use:

```
UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
   UITextField *textField = alert.textFields.firstObject;
   self.labelText1.text   = textField.text;
   // Do other stuffs
}];
```

Comment: @downvoter: Please explain the reason why you down voted, so that I can improve.

Answer (score -1):

```
UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UITextfiled *tf = alert.textFields.firstObject;
     self.labelText1.text = tf.text;

}];
```